# Insert to SQL From C# duplicate record error

Tags: c#, sql, insert, duplicates

I want to insert into a table that has unique field when users are running.
Example:

- b is unique field.
- In my c# code I'm doing this;
- get_max(b);
- y = b+1;
- insert into table1 (a, b, c, d) values (@x, @y, @z, @t)
- But users are using this table when I want to insert.  So I see duplicate record error for "b" field.

Can I allocate some records before insert or what can I do?

Comment: Look into SQL locking: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213039(v=sql.80).aspx and http://www.sqlteam.com/article/introduction-to-locking-in-sql-server

Comment: I saw Exclusive locks (X). For insert, update and delete operations I can use this.  But how can I use in c#?

Comment: I'm no expert at this; in fact, I've never had to use it. I believe you'll want to use a stored procedure that implements locking and call the stored procedure from your c# code. But you may want to post another question on SO about this specifically. Sorry I can't be of more help.

Answer (score 2):

You can't allocate records before you insert, you either have to lock the table or put the insert in a try catch block with retry logic outside of it.

for example;

```
int maxRetries = 3;

for (int i = 0; i < maxRetries; i++)
}
    try
    {
        //insert
        break;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        y = get_max(b) + 1; //get the max again since the failure is due to
        // another record incrementing that value
        if (i == maxRetries - 1)
           throw e;
        // all retries failed so it's time for that exception to bubble up
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok. I have to write this row to SQL. So I can write too big value to maxRetries field. Is this true?

Comment: @user2348397 I don't understand what you mean. maxRetries is how many times the code will attempt to insert the row before throwing an exception. If the insert is successful it breaks from the loop. maxRetries could be any integer. You could make it 1000 if you want.